# What would cause a Wireless connection to fail even though the settings are correct?

Tags: printing, wireless

I have a Canon LPB6030w wireless printer, an Archer C9 router and a Windows 10 pro /64 computer.

The printer has been working great for months, however we lost power from a storm after which the printer would not connect.

The Archer C9 router does not show the printer in the wireless connections list.
The router has the printer IP reserved with the correct MAC address.

The printer has the correct IP, subnet mask, gateway address, SSID and the security setting is correct (I can't verify the password)

However after recycling the printer power (both by on/off switch and power cord) the printer will not connect.
My solution is the cart the printer upstairs and redo the settings through the USB cable.  No changes in the router were required.

***My question is:***  What about wireless connections that might be missing for this situation to exist?   Is there some discovery process that could be missing?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with DHCP.

You say the printer has the correct IP and the router has the correct IP for the printer but that would imply the printer has static IP settings. How can the printer have the correct IP address if it doesn't have any connection to the router to receive it? It means the printer has a static IP? Verify your router is set for DHCP and that your printer is being served an IP from the router instead of you manually assigning a static IP to your printer.

Comment: Calculus, You were indeed correct!  I had set the IP as static which apparently caused this reconnect issue.  Once I changed the settings to use DHCP the issue was resolved.  For further reference It would be nice to know what the problem with static IP assignments.  Thanks for your help